# PHP echo class object property

Tags: php, echo

Is it possible to `echo` class object so it will show some property of this object?

Let's say we've got such class

```
class Color {

    public $color = "";

    function __construct($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

}
```

and then we create it's `instance` and `echo` it:

```
$myColor = new Color("red");
echo $myColor; //I want it to echo 'red' ( same as I'd do echo $myColor->color )
```

What happens here is my object has prop `color`. And when I have `echo $object` I want it to really do `echo $object->prop`

Is it possible to make such '*echoing*' handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the magic [__toString method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring):

```
class Color {

    public $color = "";

    function __construct($color) {
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function __toString() {
      return $this->color;
    }

}
```

This method will be automatically called by PHP if an instance is forced to be converted to a string, e.g. when echoing it.